# Redux: How to get the state with better code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, getstate

I'm using redux in a project and after returning an endpoint, I add a value in state,
then I need to use this value that is in the state to send in another request.

The path that is the saved value is this:

```
form.state.code.code
```

And I did this:

```
const getValue = await getState().form.state.code.code ? getState().form.state.code.code : null;
```

*I made this conditional to check if there is any value in the state, if it doesn't exist, it should return null*

This code works, **but I'm finding it very verbose**, is there any way to improve it?

Comment: you shouldn't need to await `getState`.  You could use the nullsafe-operator([optional-chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Object Destructuring

```
const {form: {state: {code = null} = null} = null} = await getState();
const getValue = code && code.code ? code.code : null;
```

or you don't need to use await `getState`, you can achieve using optional-chaning

```
const getEL = getState()
const getValue = getEL && getEL.form && getEL.form.state && getEL.form.state.code && getEL.form.state.code.code
```

Comment: How is this less verbose??